# Updating GeoJSON of countries with new and different property for each country

Tags: geojson, fields-attributes

I am trying to add a new property to my countries' GeoJSON.

```
    var countries = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "name": "countries",
    "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
    "features": [
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "NAME": "Fiji", "POP_EST": 920938 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates":
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "NAME": "Tanzania", "POP_EST": 53950935 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates":
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "NAME": "W. Sahara", "POP_EST": 603253 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates":
```

The property would be different for each country, EG 10 cases for Fiji, 20 for Tanzania.

I have tried

```
countries.properties.Fiji.cases = 10;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this data, `countries` is an object, but `countries.features` is an array.

So you need to access the elements of `countries.features` by their indices.

For example, you could do `countries.features[0].properties.cases = 10`

If you want to modify a specific country's data, you might have to loop over all the elements of the array and apply some test criteria, like this (in javascript):

```
for (let i = 0; i < countries.features.length; i++) {
  if (countries.features[i].properties.NAME === 'Fiji') {
    countries.features[i].properties.cases = 10
  }
}
```

I didn't test the code out but something along those lines should do.